# How to stop already running media player again after start other activity and start that activity by button?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I have a voice app and when i turn on the sound and move on to another activity and return to the activity that was playing the sound I want to turn off the current sound by pressing the stand button 
The mistake that happens is that when I get out of the activity and go back to it and press the stop button turns on the sound again with the first sound continuing and I just want to stop the first one

```
package com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.ui.home.innerfragment.homeactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.R;
import com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.databinding.ActivityRainpianoBinding;

public class RainpianoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    Context context;
    Button start,stop;
     private  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature ( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        getWindow ().setFlags ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
       //  setContentView(R.layout.layout.activity_rainpiano);
        final ActivityRainpianoBinding binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView (this, 
        R.layout.activity_rainpiano );

        // hid action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar ();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.hide ();

        binding.bbbb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.river_in_theforest);

        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create ( RainpianoActivity.this,R.raw.rain_light );
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping ( true );
       // rainpianoViewModel.getmAlwanarRecourceID();
        binding.play.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ( mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mMediaPlayer.pause ();
                    binding.play.setBackground ( getResources ().getDrawable ( R.drawable.play8 ) );
                }else {
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    binding.play.setBackground ( getResources ().getDrawable ( R.drawable.pause8 ) );
                }
           }
        } );
      }
     }
```

Comment: Sounds like you will need to use a service if you want a media player across multiple activities

Comment: can code please

Comment: Check google, here is a tutorial from a quick search https://sapandiwakar.in/building-a-music-player-app-for-android-2/

Comment: or [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030)

Answer (score 0):

i find The solution
build service java class

```
    package com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private  MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer,mMediaPlayer1;
    Context context;
    private static boolean isRunning;

    public static boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       // return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
       // mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create ( context,R.raw.rain_light );
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create ( this,R.raw.rain_light );
        mMediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create ( this,R.raw.forest_fire );
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping ( true );
        mMediaPlayer1.setLooping ( true );
        mMediaPlayer.start ();
        mMediaPlayer1.start ();
        isRunning = true;
        return START_STICKY;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer1.stop();
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

and main activity like thate

```
package com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.ui.home.innerfragment.homeactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.MyService;
import com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.R;
import com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.databinding.ActivityRainpianoBinding;

import static com.yasser.relaxandsleepsounds.MyService.isRunning;

public class RainpianoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    Context context;
    Button start,stop,play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature ( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        getWindow ().setFlags ( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
       //  setContentView(R.layout.layout.activity_rainpiano);
        final ActivityRainpianoBinding binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView (this, 
        R.layout.activity_rainpiano );

        // hid action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar ();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.hide ();

        binding.bbbb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.river_in_theforest);

        final Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        final Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);

        if(isRunning()){
            start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(RainpianoActivity.this, MyService.class));
                start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(RainpianoActivity.this, MyService.class));
                stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });
    }
 }
```